# For Loop in R to Transform Each Column Using Box Cox from the Cars Package

Tags: r, for-loop, transformation

I am working on an assignment for school. I need to transform the columns in a data frame using a `for` loop and the `bcPower` function from the cars package. My data frame named bb2.df consists of 13 columns of baseball statistics for 337 players. The data is from:
http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/baseball.dat.txt

I read the data in using:

```
bb.df <- read.fwf("baseball.dat.txt",widths=c(4,6,6,4,4,3,3,3,4,4,4,3,3,2,2,2,2,19))
```

And then I created a second data frame just for the numeric stats using:

```
bb2.df <- bb.df[,1:13]

library(cars)
```

Then I unsuccessfully tried to build the for loop.

```
> bb2.df[[i]] <- bcPower(bb2.df[[i]],c)
> for (i in 1:ncol(bb2.df)) {
+   c <- coef(powerTransform(bb2.df[[i]]))
+   bb2.df[[i]] <- bcPower(bb2.df[[i]],c)
+ }
Error in bc1(out[, j], lambda[j]) : 
  First argument must be strictly positive.
```

The loop seems to transform the first three columns but stops.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Difficult to say without data

Comment: do you really HAVE to use a for loop?  functions from the apply family are often better choices.

Comment: Yes, I have to use the for loop. I tried to look up how to do it and everyone seems to want to use the apply functions.

Comment: if you want to chat, I may work "across the street" from you

Comment: This is a case where a for loop doesn't seem so bad to me; I'd just loop through the numeric columns and add new versions to the original data set. Your problem, though, doesn't seem likely to have anything to do with the loop, as it's an error from the Box-Cox function. This isn't a prohibitively large number of columns (and you already think the problem is with the fourth one), so to debug, I suggest running the Box-Cox function on each column separately without the loop. I think the error is likely to make more sense when you see it immediately after the function that caused it.

Comment: The zero values in my fourth column were what was causing the error and the loop to stop. Mark's answer worked well for me.

Comment: @Tim, if you are still monitoring this... I have added some analysis of the usefulness of this transformation.  If you're new to StackOverflow...  you can mark a a response as accepted, or useful (up-voting.)

Answer (score 1):

This solution

- tests whether a column appears to contain logical values and omits them from the transformation
- replaces zero values in the vectors with a small number, outside the range of the actual values
- stores the transformed values in a new data frame, retaining the column and row names

I have also tested all of the variables for normality before and after the transformation.  I tried to find a variable that's interesting in that the transformed variable has a large p-value for the Shapiro test, but also there there was a large **change** in the p-value.  Finally, the interesting variable is scaled in both the original and transformed version, and the two versions are overlaid on a density plot.

```
library(car); library(ggplot2); library(reshape2)

# see this link for column names and type hints
# http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/baseball.txt

# add placeholder column for opening quotation mark
bb.df <-
  read.fwf(
    "http://ww2.amstat.org/publications/jse/datasets/baseball.dat.txt",
    widths = c(4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 17)
  )
# remove placeholder column
bb.df <- bb.df[,-(ncol(bb.df) - 1)]

names(bb.df) <- make.names(
  c(
    'Salary', 'Batting average', 'OBP', 'runs', 'hits', 'doubles', 'triples',
    'home runs', 'RBI', 'walks', 'strike-outs', 'stolen bases', 'errors',
    "free agency eligibility", "free agent in 1991/2" ,
    "arbitration eligibility", "arbitration in 1991/2", 'name'
  )
)

# test for boolean/logical values... don't try to transform them
logicals.test <- apply(
  bb.df,
  MARGIN = 2,
  FUN = function(one.col) {
    asnumeric <- as.numeric(one.col)
    aslogical <- as.logical(asnumeric)
    renumeric <- as.numeric(aslogical)
    matchflags <- renumeric == asnumeric
    cant.be.logical <- any(!matchflags)
    print(cant.be.logical)
  }
)

logicals.test[is.na(logicals.test)] <- FALSE

probably.numeric <- bb.df[, logicals.test]

result <- apply(probably.numeric, MARGIN = 2, function(one.col)
{
  # can't transform vectors containing non-positive values
  # replace zeros with something small
  non.zero <- one.col[one.col > 0]
  small <- min(non.zero) / max(non.zero)
  zeroless <- one.col
  zeroless[zeroless == 0] <- small
  c <- coef(powerTransform(zeroless))
  transformation <- bcPower(zeroless, c)
  return(transformation)
})

result <- as.data.frame(result)

row.names(result) <- bb.df$name

cols2test <- names(result)

normal.before <- sapply(cols2test, function(one.col) {
  print(one.col)
  temp <- shapiro.test(bb.df[, one.col])
  return(temp$p.value)
})

normal.after <- sapply(cols2test, function(one.col) {
  print(one.col)
  temp <- shapiro.test(result[, one.col])
  return(temp$p.value)
})

more.normal <- cbind.data.frame(normal.before, normal.after)
more.normal$more.normal <-
  more.normal$normal.after / more.normal$normal.before

more.normal$interest <-
  more.normal$normal.after * more.normal$more.normal

interesting <-
  rownames(more.normal)[which.max(more.normal$interest)]

data2plot <-
  cbind.data.frame(bb.df[, interesting], result[, interesting])
names(data2plot) <- c("original", "transformed")
data2plot <- scale(data2plot)
data2plot <- melt(data2plot)
names(data2plot) <- c("Var1", "dataset", interesting)

ggplot(data2plot, aes(x = data2plot[, 3], fill = dataset)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.25) + xlab(interesting)
```

[image: **Previous, incomplete response:**]

**Original, incomplete answer:**

I believe you're trying to do illegal power transformations (vectors including non-positive values, specifically zeros; vectors with no variance)

The fact that you are copying bb.df into bb2.df and then overwriting is a sure sign that you should really be using apply.

This doesn't create a useful dataframe, but it should get you started,

```
library(car)

bb.df <-
  read.fwf(
    "baseball.dat.txt",
    widths = c(4, 6, 6, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 19)
  )

bb.df[bb.df == 0] <- NA

# skip last (text) col
for (i in 1:(ncol(bb.df) - 1)) {
  print(i)
  # use comma to indicate indexing by column
  temp <- bb.df[, i]
  temp[temp == 0] <- NA
  temp <- temp[complete.cases(temp)]
  if (length(unique(temp)) > 1) {
    c <- coef(powerTransform(bb.df[, i]))
    print(bcPower(bb.df[i], c))
  } else {
    print(paste0("column ", i, " is invariant"))
  }

}

# apply solution

result <- apply(bb.df[,-ncol(bb.df)], MARGIN = 2, function(one.col)
{
  temp <- one.col
  temp[temp == 0] <- NA
  temp <- temp[complete.cases(temp)]
  if (length(unique(temp)) > 1) {
    c <- coef(powerTransform(temp))
    transformation <- bcPower(temp, c)
    return(transformation)
  } else
  {
    print("skipping invariant column")
    return(NULL)
  }
})
```